# Adding UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure - Logic issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have added a [annotaion pin point to my application](http://gigapple.files.wordpress.com/2010/05/simulatorresult.png?w=401&h=738), and when the user clicks on the pin, the popup appears with the blue arrow on it (`UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure`). Now what i want to do is, when the user clicks on it i need the view to redirect to another view with the more details about it.

for example: If its a Hospital that i click, and the popup will give its name and the `UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure` button. When i click on the `UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure` button, i should redirect to another view whcih gives more information about that hospital.

My code:

```
-(void)callingMap:(NSArray *)hospitalArray {
 for(Hospital *hospital in hospitalArray)
        {
                MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };                 
                region.center.latitude =  hospital.lati;                
                region.center.longitude = hospital.longi;
                [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];               
                DetailMap *hospitalInfo = [[DetailMap alloc] init];             
                hospitalInfo.title = [hospital name];               
                hospitalInfo.subtitle = [hospital address];     
                hospitalInfo.coordinate = region.center;                
                [self.mapView addAnnotation:hospitalInfo];            
        }   
    }    
}


-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:
(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {     
    MKAnnotationView* ann = nil;    
    if(annotation != mapView.userLocation) 
    {
        ann = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"try"];    
        ann.canShowCallout = YES;    
        ann.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"];        
        UIButton* butt = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];    
        [butt addTarget:self action:@selector(displayArrow:) forControlEvents:     
        UIControlEventTouchUpInside];        
        ann.rightCalloutAccessoryView = butt;    
    }
    return ann;
}

-(void)displayArrow:(id)sender{
        MoreHospitalDetailViewController *mhdvc = [[MoreHospitalDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

        mhdvc.hospitalArray = ????????  

        // in the MoreHospitalDetailViewController i have an Array called hospitalArray. I need to insert the selected hospital object (after clicking the particular arrow)  to this array and pass it to the next view. How to do it ?        // 
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:mhdvc animated:YES];   
}
```

In the `MoreHospitalDetailViewController` i have an Array called `hospitalArray`. I need to insert the selected `hospital object` (after clicking the particular arrow)  to this array and pass it to the next view. How to do it ?

note: There can be many items (annotations) in the map, so how do i know which hospital Object i clicked when i am in the  `(void)displayArrow:(id)sender` method ?

Help i am lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `displayArrow:` method, you can get a reference to the annotation that was clicked using:

```
DetailMap *hospitalInfo 
    = (DetailMap *)[mapView.selectedAnnotations objectAtIndex:0];
```

Note you can also use the map view's `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate method *instead of doing `addTarget` and writing a custom method*.  For example:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
    calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    DetailMap *hospitalInfo = (DetailMap *)view.annotation;

    //do something with the annotation...
}
```

---

You have two classes:

- `Hospital` which contains the full details of a hospital including phone#, etc.
- `DetailMap` which implements `MKAnnotation` and contains just a hospital's coordinate, name, and address (*but not the phone# or anything else*)

When tapping the callout button of an annotation, *you want to get access to the full hospital info* (not just coordinate, name, and address).

First, when you say in the comments "DetailMap which only contains 2 records", you really mean "fields" or "properties" instead of "records" (each hospital object is a "record").

Here are a couple of ways to solve this:

- In `DetailMap`, add a property called say `hospital` of type `Hospital` and set it when creating `DetailMap` objects in the `callingMap` method (`hospitalInfo.hospital = hospital`).  Then in the `displayArrow:` method, you can add that property to the array (`mhdvc.hospitalArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:hospitalInfo.hospital];`).
- Change the `Hospital` class so that it implements `MKAnnotation` itself and eliminate the `DetailMap` class entirely.  Then you can directly pass `Hospital` objects to `addAnnotation` and in the `displayArrow:` method you would do this:

  ```
  Hospital *hospital = (Hospital *)[mapView.selectedAnnotations objectAtIndex:0];
  mhdvc.hospitalArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:hospital];
  ```

The first option is easier since you've already created the `DetailMap` class but the second one is cleaner.

Still, the `MoreHospitalDetailViewController` doesn't need an array to pass the single hospital object (which contains multiple fields).  You could just declare a `Hospital *hospital` property in `MoreHospitalDetailViewController` to pass the single object.

Comment: But what i need is an Array of `Hospital` objects. So how can i get an Array of `Hospital` objects with `DetailMap ` ? Please Help

Comment: Which hospital objects do you want to pass to MoreHospitalDetailViewController?

Comment: When the user clicks on the blue arrow the `displayArrow` method gets called. When he selects a particular record i need to add that particular `hospital` object to an NSMutableArray and then convert it to an array and pass it to `MoreHospitalDetailViewController`'s array.  

In the `callingMap` method you will see the `Hospital` object which i am using to extract details and display on the annotation. So when the user clicks on a hospital in the map, i need to add this hospital object to a Array and pass it to `MoreHospitalDetailViewController`

Comment: So the array would only contain the single, selected annotation?  Not sure why you want to pass as an array but you can do `mhdvc.hospitalArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:hospitalInfo];`.

Comment: Because `MoreHospitalDetailViewController` requires an Array of Hospitals to display more information about the selected hospital. `hospitalInfo` only contains hospital name, and address and we assign values to this using the `hospital ` object (look at `callingMap:` method). So is there anyway where we could pass an array to `MoreHospitalDetailViewController` which contains information stored in the `Hospital` Object ? and Yes the array would contain a single `Hospital` object

Comment: Yes, try the line in my previous comment and also include the `DetailMap *hospitalInfo = ...` code above that.

Comment: The object `hospitalInfo ` which belongs to the class `DetailMap ` only contains 2 records. Hospital Name, and Hospital address. I need some more information like hosp tele number, etc to be displayed in the other view. The `hospitalArray ` is an array of `Hospital` objects. So i need a way to grab its content and pass it to an array and then send it to the other view. In your code you are passing the object of `DetailMap ` which contains only 2 records. But i need all the records that contains in the `Hospital` object. (Sorry, i am a beginner :( )

Comment: Thank you Anna, i am stuck with this issue for awhile now. Hope you could help me.

Comment: Thank you Anna, i am not in my mac right now, i'll update you soon